# Should this class inherit from directly from the base class or from the subclass

Tags: class, inheritance, uml

I have the following class diagram.  Just looking for some guidance as to how I approached this exam question as I'm not sure if I was correct. I have no solutions am hoping someone more experienced could give there opinion.

[image]

- **TASK 1:**   Add a subclass called `MonsterEater`. Objects of this class are like `PieEaters` but in addition the `MonsterEater` has an attribute called `numPieEatersEaten` of type integer and a method `eatPieEater` with signature of one argument named `aGrid` which is of type `Grid`.

  Since `MonsterEater` has a lot of the same behaviours as `PieEater` I decided to make that inherit from the `PieEater` class, while giving it the additional behaviour (attributes and methods)
- **TASK 2**:   Add a subclass called `MagicPie`. Objects of this class are like `Pies` but in addition the `MagicPies` have an attribute called `visible` of type boolean and methods appear and disappear both with signature of no arguments and return nothing

  I made `MagicPie` inherit from `Pie`. Gave it the attributes and methods.
- **TASK 3**:   Override the display method in all the concrete classes in your inheritance hierarchy.

  For this I just added the method `display()` to all the classes which inherit from the base class `GameElement`.

  I was also asked to add an association so that just `MonsterEaters` may eat `MagicPies`.(the class i made derive from `Pie`) so I've done an `eats` association from `MonsterEater` to `MagicPie`
- **FINAL TASK:**   List all the features of the `MonsterEater` and `MagicPie` classes. Does the UML diagram that you produced allow `MonsterEaters` to eat `Pies`. Explain your answer.

  I wasnt to sure about this one, `MonsterEater` inherits from the `PieEater` class which can eat a pie but I'm not sure if that means `MonsterEater` can. I'm also not fully sure if my inheritance hierachy that I created is even correct.  Any insight/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Task 1:** If `MonsterEater` is allowed to eat Pie as well, then your inheritance relation seems acceptable.  I'd also add an association 0..1 to 0..n from `MonsterEater` to `PieEater`.  THis makes obvious the implication of this inheritance: a `MonsterEater` can also eat another `MonsterEater` because it's also a `PieEater`.

**Task 2:**  The inheritance makes sense, as intuitively a `MagicPie` is some special kind of `Pie`.  But the consequence of this inheritance, is that `PieEater` could also eat `MagicPie` (see below)

**Task 3:** ok for the display.  ok for the additional association.  But there's a trap here.  As a `MagicPie` is a `Pie`,  a `PieEater` could also eat a `MagicPie`.  So you have to add a constraint to the existing association between `PieEater` and `Pie`, for example:  `{ Pie shall not be a MagicPie }`

**Task 4:** For nutrition, see above. The inheritance you've made seem reasonable. The wording of the instructions "*are like ... but in addition ...*"  strongly suggests inheritance.  Only if `MonsterEater` would not be allowed to eat `Pie` would I seriously question this inheritance.  And this is not explicitly prohibited.

Comment: thanks would i be right in saying that a monserEater could also eat a pie as monsterEater is also a pieEater? would i have to show this association or would be implied through the association pieEater eats pie?  It also asks for the features of the monsterEater and magicPie class what would they be?

Comment: @stephenreilly yes, you would be right. The association is implied, no need to show it. For the features, i would list those of the class and its parent.

Comment: as in list all the things it can do? like eat a pie, walk, turn etc.

Comment: @stephenreilly attributes + operations + associations

Comment: If it cannot eat MagicPie, then I would use a NormalPie class and not relying on runtime checks.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't let MonsterEater inherit from PieEater if it doesn't eat pies, the fact that they both have eat/walk/turn methods probably means they should implement few new interfaces: IEater, IWalker.

A MagicPie inheriting from a Pie makes more sense as it appears to be an extension of a normal Pie.

Depending on the UML tool you have, you might have to specify display() is an override.

The last question, reconnecting to my first observation, it's a matter of requeirements, you can do it both ways, if it's not specified, I wouldn't assume a MonsterEater can eat a Pie as well.

EDIT: If you are allowed to use multiple inheritance, you may also use classes instead of interfaces for Eater/Walker.

Comment: yeah that makes sense thank you. So even though MonsterEater has the eatpie() method the fact that it does not have an eat association to Pie i can assume it cannot eat a pie? Also what would be the features? the things it can do?

Comment: And at the end i was asked to label in terms of base class, subclass and leaf classes, i understand how to label everything except grid class. would that be a base class?

Comment: That would be up to the design again, but, not having any inheritor, it's a leaf class. To be blocked from having sub classes, it should have a "sealed/final" stereotype. But I guess now I'm thinking too much about the implementation in languages.